# JSONata: method or function for testing JSON value datatype

Tags: jsonata

JSONata offers conditional expressions and predicates which can be used to select values out of JSON trees.

However, I have not been able to find a way to test the datatype of a JSON value.

For example, given the array:

```
    [null, true, false, 1, 2.3, "a", ["x"], {}, {"y" : "z}]
```

I only want to pull out the numeric values.

```
    [1, 2.3]
```

Q: In a JSONata query, how does one test the JSON datatype (null, boolean, number, string, array, object) of a value?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to do this in JSONata.  Worthy of an enhancement request though.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, today discovered this cool JSONata. Here is my try:

http://try.jsonata.org/

```
 [null, true, false, 1, 2.3, "a", ["x"], {}, {"y" : "z"}]
```

```
*[$ ~> /^[0-9\.]{1,}$/m]
```

Answer (score 2):

JSONata offers the `$type`-method to check datatype of a JSON value. For example. the following snippet will return the datatypes of the values in the invoices example data in https://try.jsonata.org.

```
Account.Order.Product.{
    "priceType": $type(Price),
    "productNameType": $type($.'Product Name'),
    "descriptionType": $type(Description)
}
```

The result is:

```
[
  {
    "priceType": "number",
    "productNameType": "string",
    "descriptionType": "object"
  },
  {
    "priceType": "number",
    "productNameType": "string",
    "descriptionType": "object"
  },
  {
    "priceType": "number",
    "productNameType": "string",
    "descriptionType": "object"
  },
  {
    "priceType": "number",
    "productNameType": "string",
    "descriptionType": "object"
  }
]
```

By changing values of `Price` and `Product Name` to `null` in the example JSON, the result will change for that particular object to:

```
{
    "priceType": "null",
    "productNameType": "null",
    "descriptionType": "object"
},
```

One can check for 'null', 'number', 'string', 'array', 'object', 'boolean'.

For my concern I've used it to check for null values when converting dates to milliseconds:

```
'enddate': $type($v.enddate) = 'null' ? null : $toMillis($v.enddate),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a value is a number doing `value - value = 0`. In case of type is number it will always be 0, so result will be `true`. It will trigger an error if it is a string.

Comment: Imagine a system that does that check thousands of times per minute, generating a log entry for this error.. Hmm. This would spamming log files easily.